# Using if condition in Dialog flow not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am trying to calculate the percentage of people whose age is greater than 24. The issue is i am getting error in if condition since i am very new to dialog flow and doesn't know much about syntax.
This is the structure of my data.

```js
function Calpercentage(agent) {
  return admin.database().ref('data').once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let percentage = 0;
      let totalCount = 0;
      let totalcategoryCount = 0;
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        var value = childSnapshot.val();
        if (value.Age) > 24 {
          totalcategoryCount += 1;
        };
        totalCount += 1;
        percentage = (totalcategoryCount / totalCount) * 100;
      });
      if (age !== null) {
        agent.add(`The total counts from database is ${percentage}`);
      }
    });
}
```

Structure of my data

[image]

Comment: Your snippet even tells you where to look

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis is wrong. Change this

```
if (value.Age) >24{
    totalcategoryCount+=1;  
};
```

to

```
if (value.Age >24 ){
    totalcategoryCount+=1;  
};
```

Next time post your error and tell us what you have tried.